# Export a specific non-default database using drush sql-dump

Tags: 7, database, drush

My Drupal 7 site connects to multiple databases using a `$databases` array like this:

```
$databases = [
  'default' => [
    'default' => [
      'database' => 'examplecom',
      'username' => 'example',
      'password' => 'sostrongpassword',
      'host' => '',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ],
  ],
  'nondefault' => [
    'default' => [
      'database' => 'notdefaultdb',
      'username' => 'notdefaultuser',
      'password' => 'notdefaultpass',
      'host' => '',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ],
  ],
];
```

Ideally I want to be able to do something like `drush --database-key=nondefault sql-dump > myfile.sql` but I don't see a way in drush to do that. Is it possible?

I tried creating a custom script to do this like:

```
drush_sql_bootstrap_further();
db_set_active('nondefault');
$sql = drush_sql_get_class();
return $sql->connect(FALSE);
```

And then calling that script with `drush scr foo.php` but the sql connect (or any other command) seem to work against the default database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Drush 8 docs, there is a --database=key option that does what you want.

I've verified it against a D8 site with multiple databases using the command:

```
drush @dev sql-dump --database="blog_import" > ~/tmp/blog_import.sql
```

The drush sql-cli command also has the same option so you should be able to import the dump using a command like:

```
drush @dev sql-cli --database="blog_import" < ~/tmp/blog_import.sql
```